# A better way to reference theorem-like environments?

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems

I know how to use \label and \ref to get a reference to a result(or whatever else really) that I have made previously in the document. But this is tedious and requires me to create a label name every time.

What I am wondering, is if there is a more systematic/powerful way to accomplish this. I suppose there are many ways to skin a cat, so I will word the question like this;

> How do you reference theorem-like environments in your LaTeX documents, and why do you do so in this way?

Since I am asking the question in a way that suggest multiple answers with some opinions, I am marking this CW and putting the Big-list tag. If this is wrong, feel free to change.

Comment: What is a "theorem style"?

Comment: defined theorem environments? Sorry if I am using strange terminology, I mean things like lemma, thm, corollary, etc.

Comment: I think this question shouldn’t be `big-list` and cw. (but cw can’t be undone)

Comment: So you want an autogenerated label or something? How would you know what to use? It seems like the best you could get is saving yourself typing `\label` for each theorem.

Comment: Or is the question "How do you label your theorems?" i.e. What conventions are good for naming your labels?

Comment: It seems to me not to be the question, but in response to Seamus: I used to use the laconic style `\label{thm:z_lemma}` or some such, but then I realized you can use spaces in the label.  Now I'll write `\label{zorn's lemma}` or even something crazy like `\label{bounded chains imply maximal elements}` (which, if I were Zorn, I probably would have used in the original paper).  Then I can be sure (on checking) that I have referenced the right theorem.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I solved this problem for myself a few years ago without knowing about the `theoremref` or `ntheorem` packages, but those in themselves do not do what you want anyway.

The problems that I had with the standard setup were the following:

1. You have to give each theorem type a different environment, which has both a "begin" and "end" tag containing the name of the theorem.  If you want to make a change, you have to change two words not near each other.
2. You have to write `\label` every time.
3. You have to remember the name of the theorem type whenever you use `\ref`.  This is the problem which `theoremref` also solves, though I think they do it in a slightly different way than I did.
4. The hyperlink produced by `ref` (when using `hyperref`) only encompasses the number and not the name ("Theorem 2", etc.), which is a small target but to change it is awkward.

I dealt with 1 and 2 by overwriting the `theorem` environment with one that has the syntax

```
\begin{theorem}{theorem type}{name of label} ... \end{theorem}
```

thus solving the locality problem for the theorem type and also allowing me to omit `\label`.  For 3, I used the `fncylab` package to do the work that `theoremref` does (note that at the time, there was a bug in `amsthm` which makes this impossible without some work.  It may be fixed now).  This also takes care of 4, since now the word "Theorem" is part of the text produced by `\ref`, which is all wrapped in a hyperlink without my needing to do anything.

I like this solution very much.  I write things like

```
\begin{theorem}{lem}{little lemma} This is a small lemma. \end{theorem}
It follows from \ref{little lemma} that we have
\begin{theorem*}{thm} The main result. \end{theorem*}
```

You can guess the effect of a `theorem*` environment, of course.  You can see the .sty file on my website if you are interested.

**Later:** I just found out about the `thmtools` package.  Man, that thing is awesome.  I wish I had known about it.  It does everything above (and more) and uses a keyval syntax for setting parameters, which is far better than having multiple arguments.  Read p. 8 of its manual to see my hack done right. (It's not quite the same: it doesn't address point 1.  However, I can imagine writing a wrapper environment taking a key "type" that would duplicate the above example.)

Comment: Thank you! This is PERFECT! Also I appreciate you explaining why you wanted this hack yourself, I was having difficulty expressing myself in my question, but you captured it perfectly. Thanks so much.

Comment: @RyanReich what was your solution?

Comment: Hello Ryan, I'm trying to find the source code for your overwritten theorem and theorem* environments; however, I'm having difficulty finding your website. Do you have a hyperlink or, if you have the time, could you post the code here?

Answer (score 16):

If you use `ntheorem` package, this allows you to use `\thref` to reference theorem environments in a smart way. So it will reference a theorem as "Theorem 1" and a lemma as "Lemma 2" automatically.

`hyperref` will also automatically do the same sort of thing with its `\autoref` command.

Answer (score 8):

Check out the `coolthms` package (admitedly, I am one of its authors). We were facing similar problems, especially regarding labeling lists nested in theorem environments (cf [this related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12055/references-to-lists-in-theorem-like-environments-writing-symbol-to-files)) and used `ntheorem` for the formating and `cleveref` for the references, allowing for a single (!) reference to have the form (e.g.) "Theorem 1 (a)". We're still looking for people to test it and give feedback :)

The idea is to create a new `\Label` command for a list nested in a "theorem-like" environment that includes the theorem name and number in its formating.

Comment: @downvoter: care to explain your reasoning?! Did you actually test the package and figure it was that bad? How about some constructive criticism then? I was faced with _exactly_ the same problem some years ago and my solution was to write a package that fixed it for me and post it on CTAN. Why is it incorrect to mention that in answer to this question?

Comment: up-voting you because I feel the down-vote here without an explanation was inappropriate.

Answer (score 3):

How would the auto-labelling work?  If there were a way of generating, say, `\label{thm1}`, `\label{thm2}`, and so on, then you couldn't rearrange the theorems or insert new ones without the labels automatically changing.  And if you're willing to forswear such edits, then you might as well write `Theorem 1` in the source, and skip the `\label` business entirely.