# How to get more complete references

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

Sometimes when I work I write something like

```
\begin{proposition} \label{my new result}
...
\end{proposition}
...
blah blah in Proposition \ref{my new result} blah...
```

but then I realize that the Proposition should actually become a Lemma. So I change it to

```
\begin{lemma} \label{my new result}
...
\end{lemma}
```

The problem is that I then have to hunt down all the places where I wrote Proposition and change it to Lemma, which is tedious and error-prone. Well, we have search facilities in editors, so it is not really that complicated, but still it feels the wrong way to do this. I would be happier to write

```
\begin{proposition} \label{my new result}
...
\end{proposition}
...
blah blah in \labelNameFor{my new result} \ref{my new result} blah...
```

where labelNameFor is a hypothetical magic command which outputs "Proposition". Then I could forget about all the places where I reference the result and just make any changes I wish.

Is there a way to do something like this? As far as I understand the label/ref mechanism is simply based on counters, so I do not see a straightforward way, but maybe someone more clever and industrious then I am has given the problem some thought.

Comment: Good question.  I had a hack for this in my thesis, but I'll wait a bit to see if anyone has a proper solution before offering that up.

Comment: Maybe your question is answered [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2450/1235). (Possible duplicate?)

Comment: It seems to me that the question there is different, but there are many answers for my question! :-)

Comment: Your right, just looking at the _questions_ it's definitely not a duplicate. I only looked at the answers, which I found very useful.

Comment: It is also easy to do it yourself as discussed in [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5797/1235).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I recommend to use the [`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package which enhances LaTeX's cross-referencing features determining types of cross-references and context.

In your case, `\cref{my new result}` would output *proposition 1*. If you then change this particular environment into a `lemma` environment, the same `\cref{my new result}` would output *lemma 1*.

You could even change the referencing name for an environment in the whole document if you would like to change the style completely. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\begin{document}
\begin{proposition}\label{my new result}
...
\end{proposition}
...
blah blah in \Cref{my new result} blah...
\end{document}
```

outputs *... blah blah in Proposition 1 blah...*

If you add this modification to the preamble

```
\Crefname{proposition}{Lemma}{Lemmas}
\crefname{proposition}{lemma}{lemmas}
```

the output changes to *... blah blah in Lemma 1 blah...*

Other packages with similar features are [`ntheorem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) (with `thref` option), [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) (with `\autoref`) and [`fancyref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyref). Your question might be solved by any of them, though `cleveref` seems to be more flexible and generally provides more features - have a look at it if you're interested in further features for your theorem environments or for cross-referencing in general.

Comment: If I understand correctly, that would change all Propositions in Lemmas, right? I need a tool which is able to figure out that I changed a particular Proposition to a Lemma.

Comment: \cref does it as well - if you change to `\begin{lemma}\label{my new result} ... \end{lemma}` then `\cref{my new result}` outputs *lemma 1*.

Comment: @Andrea: as I read *hunt down all the places where I wrote Proposition and change it to Lemma* I firstly assumed you wish to switch from propositions to lemma completely, so I came up with `\crefname`.

Comment: Should the "c" in `\cref` and `\crefname` be capitalized or not?

Comment: @FangJing There are two versions, capitalized and not, see the manual (texdoc cleveref).

Answer (score 11):

The [`ntheorem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) package handles this nicely with its `\thref` command.

Another option would be to make use of [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) and its `\autoref` command.

Both of these would obviate the need to hunt down all instances of the reference.

So instead of writing `Proposition \ref{thm:label}` you'd just write `\autoref{thm:label}`. Then, if you later changed the theorem to a lemma, `\autoref` would automatically update (after two compiles...)

Answer (score 6):

This question is very similar to a previous one, as noted.  [Here is](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2450/what-is-the-correct-way-to-reference-theorem-styles-in-latex/2466#2466) my (accepted) answer to that question.  Summary: use `fncylab`.

To address your comment that referencing is based on counters: this is true, but that does not preclude a more detailed scheme like you want!  In fact, every counter is a bundle of several related macros (in C it would be a `struct`) one of which is called `p@<counter name>` and contains material to be printed before the counter number when used in a reference.  The `fncylab` package actually modifies this (in a manner suggested in the LaTeX sources themselves) so that `p@<counter name>` can be a macro taking the number as an argument.

Comment: As the comments to the question show: It hasn't been _asked_ there, but your answer there is great.

Comment: Corrected already!