# Auto recognize reference types

Tags: cross-referencing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get more complete references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5767/how-to-get-more-complete-references)

Is there a way to recognize cross-reference types automatically in LaTeX?
For example, see the code below

```
\begin{lemma}\label{triangle}%

\[
a^{2}=b^{2}+c^{2}\text{.}%
\]

\end{lemma}



\begin{theorem}

\bigskip From \ref{triangle}, we have
\[
E=mc^{2}\text{.}%
\]

\end{theorem}
```

As you see, when I reference the lemma in the theorem, the LaTeX only displays the number of the lemma in the compiled pdf file. In fact, I hope LaTeX can recognize reference types. For e.g., when I reference a lemma, then LaTeX displays automatically both lemma and its number (such as lemma 2.1, not just the number 2.1 of this lemma) in the compiled pdf file; when I reference a theorem, then LaTeX automatically displays both theorem and its number (such as theorem 3.7, not just the number 3.7 of this theorem ) in the compiled pdf file.

Comment: Better avoid empty lines before and after displayed equations, this can cause undesired additional vertical space. equation have already their own spacing, you don't need to break a paragraph by an empty line.

Comment: Looks like a dupe to me

Comment: @user9701 Have a look at the question linkes by whlt3. Since it's very similar, we will close this question. In such cases a question can be reopened if it's edited with new, different information.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package for this. It is able to automatically determine the format of references according to the type of reference. By `\crefname` you can specify singular and plural versions of the name you would like to use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\crefname{lemma}{lemma}{lemmas}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{lemma}\label{triangle}%
\[
  a^{2}=b^{2}+c^{2}\text{.}%
\]
\end{lemma}
\begin{theorem}
\bigskip From \cref{triangle}, we have
\[
  E=mc^{2}\text{.}%
\]
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image: lemma referenced by name]

Comment: I posted the answer before I noticed the duplicate. I still let it here for the OP for now.