# `\ref` including "lemma", "theorem", "section" or whatever

Tags: labels

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get more complete references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5767/how-to-get-more-complete-references)

`\ref` itself only prints the number of whatever I am referencing - e.g. a chapter/section/subsection or a theorem/lemma/definition (from `amsthm` via `\newtheorem`).

I would like to have a command which prints also what the `\ref`-number actually is. Right now, I am doing it manually as in "`in lemma \ref{...}`" or "`in section \ref{...}`".

Sometimes I move a `\label` somewhere else or make the labeled lemma a theorem or so and I don't want to search manually through the rest of my code to update it (section -> chapter, lemma -> theorem, ...).

Comment: We ought to add this one to the FAQ, or make a "sticky" question somehow that floats to the top.  It is surely our most FAQ.

Comment: @RyanReich There are a good dozen of "repetitive questions". And this is only 3rd question linked to "How to get more complete references".

Comment: @tohecz Perhaps it's just bias, but it seems like this one comes up every other week.  Not that it's a bad question; just that it's a very popular one.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I was too stupid to search. It looks like the package [`cleveref`](http://www.dr-qubit.org/latex/cleveref.pdf) does mostly what I want.