# Creating a new type of cross reference and referencing them spelling the same text

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering

I would like to create 2 commands

```
\newcommand\deffeat[1]...
\newcommand\reffeat[1] ...
```

The `deffeat` command would print out as something like `\textbf{F001}`,

and the `reffeat` command would reference the `deffeat` with the same feature name plus have the exact same text.

My current experiment is using the following:

```
\newcounter{thefeatures}
\setcounter{thefeatures}{1}

\newcommand{\deffeat}[1]{
    \phantomsection[a]
    %XXX: \tag{F~\{cifeatures}}
    \label{#1}
    \textbf{F~\arabic{thefeatures}}
    \addtocounter{thefeatures}{1}
}
```

It's still missing the spell the same text feature (currently I'm using `\ref`).

*edit* current state:

```
using cleveref

\newcounter{thefeatures}
\setcounter{thefeatures}{0}

\crefname{thefeatures}{feature}{features}

\newcommand{\deffeat}[1]{
    \phantomsection
    \refstepcounter{thefeatures}
    \label{#1}
    \textbf{F\arabic{thefeatures}}
}

\crefformat{thefeatures}{#2F#1#3}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, `\ref` prints only the number of the reference. Take a look at the [`cleveref`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref) package to print the name, too. Some minor customization is required for the new reference type, check `\crefname` in the cleveref manual.

Note that your example had several minor deficiencies, and also is incomplete. A full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would have been better. Anyway, the following pattern should help achieving what you are looking for:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcounter{thefeatures}
\setcounter{thefeatures}{0}

\crefname{thefeatures}{feature}{features}

\newcommand{\deffeat}[1]{
    \phantomsection
    \refstepcounter{thefeatures}
    \label{#1}
    \textbf{F~\arabic{thefeatures}}
}

\begin{document}
    \deffeat{MyFeature}

    \deffeat{MyFeature2}

    \Cref{MyFeature,MyFeature2}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of compilation]

As you can see, the package tries hard to be clever.

See this related question: [How to get more complete references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5767/how-to-get-more-complete-references).

Comment: i dont see how i could use the same text for the definition site and the reference site tho (ideally formated as F followed by 3 digits)

Comment: @Ronny: See Section 7.2 of the `cleveref` manual on full control of reference formatting. Something along the lines of `\crefformat{thefeatures}{#2F\prependzeros[3]{#1}#3}` should do the trick, but `\prependzeros[3]{#1}` is a macro still to be implemented, perhaps using the `stringstrings` package.

Comment: i implemented the part without prependzeroes to see if it works
however i get a undefined reference when doing `\Cref{test}` after a `\deffeat{test}`

Comment: @Ronny: Does `\cref{test}` work? Have you used `\Crefformat`?

Comment: cref wont work , i tried with and without Crefformat

Comment: full stop, i found a badly placed usepackage for hyperref
i fixed the order and everything works now

Comment: Right: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before