# How do I configure a \ref of a \label to print more than just the number?

Tags: cross-referencing

I am using `\label` in conjunction with `\ref` for my equations. For example

```
\begin{equation} 
\label{eq:grav} F=\frac{G m_{1} m_{2}}{r^{2}}
\end{equation}
```

as shown in equation `\ref{eq:grav}`

which prints the number for the order the equation is placed (with reference to the other equations in the document).

I would like it to print the word "equation" as well as just the number, since I always need to say it's an equation it would be nice not to have to type it out manually all the time. Same with figures.

Is there a way to define this in the preamble?

Comment: You can use `cleveref` for this. There is a duplicate in the site.

Comment: @HarishKumar link please?

Comment: [Difference between ref, varioref and cleveref. Decision for a thesis](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83051)

Comment: Thanks for the link but that is a different question altogether. That question is asking for the differences between 3 packages. Here I ask how to do something quite specific which may or may not be answered by using one of those packages.

Comment: Just a suggestion: usually equations are cited using parenthesis, so you can use `\eqref{}` from the package `amsmath` instead of `\ref{}`.

Comment: Perhaps a better suggestion for a duplicate is: [How to get more complete references](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5767/2693). And for a comprehensive review of almost all the packages: [Cross-reference packages: which to use, which conflict?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36295/2693).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref} %% to turn the links clickable and load this before cleveref
\usepackage{cleveref}

% each of the following has two versions
%   \crefname{environmentname}{singular}{plural}, to be used mid-sentence
%   \Crefname{environmentname}{singular}{plural}, to be used at the beginning of a sentence
\crefname{table}{table}{tables}
\Crefname{table}{Table}{Tables}
\crefname{figure}{figure}{figures}
\Crefname{figure}{Figure}{Figures}
\crefname{equation}{equation}{equations}
\Crefname{Equation}{Equation}{Equation}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
  \centering
  \rule{20pt}{20pt}
  \caption{My figure}
  \label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:grav} F=\frac{G m_{1} m_{2}}{r^{2}}
\end{equation}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Use \cref{fig:myfig} mid sentence.
  \item \Cref{fig:myfig} is appropriate for the beginning of a sentence and~\cref{eq:grav}. \Cref{eq:grav} is printing \verb|Equation| rather than \verb|equation|.
\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm that didn't work until I tried compiling a copy of your exact example which did work. It seems to be not able to print them in my own document though. ARe there any package conflicts that could cause this?

Comment: @Magpie Without knowing which packages you have in your preamble, it is difficult to say. May be you reduce your document to a MWE and ask a new follow up question?

Answer (score 4):

Mine is similar to that offered by Harish Kumar, except I offer a few added options. What I provide below is a style file, eqcite.sty

```
\ProvidesPackage {eqcite} [2006/11/29]
%
% by Steven B. Segletes, for the public domain.
%
% eqcite prints out the preferred reference format for equation
% citations, e.g., equation 1 as opposed to eqn(1), eq.(1), etc. 
%
% Advantages of using eqcite:
% 1) Ability to quickly change from `equation x' to `eqn(x)' through
%    whole document, with a single line change (\EqTypeB).  This is 
%    useful when converting from tech report to manuscript formats;
% 2) Saves typing:
%    With the eqcite package, type        `\eqcite{eq:myeqn}'
%    vs. the traditional LaTeX approach of `equation~\ref{eq:myeqn}'  .
%
%
% A number of format types are predefined:
%
% EqTypeA : equation x, equations x and y   (ARL report standard)
% EqTypeB : eqn(x)    , eqns (x) and (y)
% EqTypeC : eq(x)     , eqs (x) and (y)
% EqTypeD : eqn.(x)   , eqns. (x) and (y)
% EqTypeE : eq.(x)    , eqs. (x) and (y)
% EqTypeF : eqn (x)   , eqns (x) and (y)
% EqTypeG : eq (x)    , eqs (x) and (y)
%
% Other format types are easily added.
%
% Usage:
%
% % In Preamble:
% \usepackage{eqcite}
% \EqTypex  % where `x' is A, B, etc.  defaults to EqTypeA
%
% % In Document:
% \Eqcite{ref} ...
% ... \eqcite{ref} ...
% \Eqcites{ref1}, \andeqcite{ref2}, and \andeqcite{ref3} ...
% ... \eqcites{ref1}, \andeqcite{ref2}, and \andeqcite{ref3}...
%
% where ref is the LaTeX reference, for example, eq:myeqn  .
%
% A literal option [l] is available to use the the argument as the
% actual equation number, rather than as an equation reference:
%
% \eqcite[l]{13}
%
% This literal option can be used with the following calls:
% \Eqcite, \eqcite, \Eqcites, \eqcites and \andeqcite.
%
%
% EqTypeA : equation x, equations x and y
\newcommand\EqTypeA{
  \def\Eqname{Equation}
  \def\eqname{equation}
  \def\Eqsname{Equations}
  \def\eqsname{equations}
  \def\eqsep{~}
  \def\eqssep{~}
  \def\eqldelimit{}
  \def\eqrdelimit{}
}
% EqTypeB : eqn(x), eqns (x) and (y)
\newcommand\EqTypeB{
  \def\Eqname{Eqn}
  \def\eqname{eqn}
  \def\Eqsname{Eqns}
  \def\eqsname{eqns}
  \def\eqsep{}
  \def\eqssep{~}
  \def\eqldelimit{(}
  \def\eqrdelimit{)}
}
% EqTypeC : eq(x), eqs (x) and (y)
\newcommand\EqTypeC{
  \def\Eqname{Eq}
  \def\eqname{eq}
  \def\Eqsname{Eqs}
  \def\eqsname{eqs}
  \def\eqsep{}
  \def\eqssep{~}
  \def\eqldelimit{(}
  \def\eqrdelimit{)}
}
% EqTypeD : eqn.(x), eqns. (x) and (y)
\newcommand\EqTypeD{
  \def\eqname{Eqn.}
  \def\eqname{eqn.}
  \def\Eqsname{Eqns.}
  \def\eqsname{eqns.}
  \def\eqsep{}
  \def\eqssep{~}
  \def\eqldelimit{(}
  \def\eqrdelimit{)}
}
% EqTypeE : eq.(x), eqs. (x) and (y)
\newcommand\EqTypeE{
  \def\Eqname{Eq.}
  \def\eqname{eq.}
  \def\Eqsname{Eqs.}
  \def\eqsname{eqs.}
  \def\eqsep{}
  \def\eqssep{~}
  \def\eqldelimit{(}
  \def\eqrdelimit{)}
}
% EqTypeF : eqn (x), eqns (x) and (y)
\newcommand\EqTypeF{
  \def\Eqname{Eqn}
  \def\eqname{eqn}
  \def\Eqsname{Eqns}
  \def\eqsname{eqns}
  \def\eqsep{~}
  \def\eqssep{~}
  \def\eqldelimit{(}
  \def\eqrdelimit{)}
}
% EqTypeG : eq (x), eqs (x) and (y)
\newcommand\EqTypeG{
  \def\Eqname{Eq}
  \def\eqname{eq}
  \def\Eqsname{Eqs}
  \def\eqsname{eqs}
  \def\eqsep{~}
  \def\eqssep{~}
  \def\eqldelimit{(}
  \def\eqrdelimit{)}
}
% Default to Equation Type A format
\EqTypeA
%
% For citing an equation at the beginning of a sentence
\newcommand\Eqcite[2][]{%
  \if l#1%
    \Eqname\eqsep\eqldelimit#2\eqrdelimit
  \else%
    \Eqname\eqsep\eqldelimit\ref{#2}\eqrdelimit
  \fi
}
% For citing an equation in the middle of a sentence
\newcommand\eqcite[2][]{%
  \if l#1%
    \eqname\eqsep\eqldelimit#2\eqrdelimit
  \else%
    \eqname\eqsep\eqldelimit\ref{#2}\eqrdelimit
  \fi
}
% For citing the first of multiple equations at the beginning of a sentence
\newcommand\Eqcites[2][]{%
  \if l#1%
    \Eqsname\eqssep\eqldelimit#2\eqrdelimit
  \else%
    \Eqsname\eqssep\eqldelimit\ref{#2}\eqrdelimit
  \fi
}
% For citing the first of multiple equations in the middle of a sentence
\newcommand\eqcites[2][]{%
  \if l#1%
    \eqsname\eqssep\eqldelimit#2\eqrdelimit
  \else%
    \eqsname\eqssep\eqldelimit\ref{#2}\eqrdelimit
  \fi
}
% For citing an equation number without the leading word equation, eqn, etc.
% Used in conjuction with \Eqcites and \eqcites
\newcommand\andeqcite[2][]{%
  \if l#1%
    \eqldelimit#2\eqrdelimit
  \else%
    \eqldelimit\ref{#2}\eqrdelimit
  \fi
}
%
% For backward compatibility to equagen.sty
\let\equagen\eqcite
\let\Equagen\Eqcite
\let\equagens\eqcites
\let\Equagens\Eqcites
\let\andequagen\andeqcite

\endinput
```

First, you can specify the EqType, where the type could be  "equation", "eqn" etc. Then, it offers, plural, singular, capitalized, conjunctive, and literal options for the cite.

Comment: Ohh this looks more like the sort of thing I need. How/where do I implement it?

Comment: @Magpie You extract the code and call it eqcite.sty.  Then in your tex file, you say `\usepackage{eqcite}`.  Then you start using its commands in your file.  Since I didn't upload to CTAN, you can't get it auto-installed.  Thus, this file needs to be put in your localtexmf directory structure, or else kept in the directory where you are compiling your code.