# Can the result of `\eqref{eq:einsten}` be something other than the default number?

Tags: cross-referencing

When I use \eqref, it produce, say, (2.5).
It is possible to produce like "my owner words"?

Comment: Use `\tag{Something}` inside the equation.

Comment: at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103546/how-do-i-configure-a-ref-of-a-label-to-print-more-than-just-the-number/103553#103553 is a way to change the label, if you want it to say, for example, eqn(2.5) or equation (2.5) rather than (2.5).  It is convenient way to change all the equation references at once, with a single change, but would not be the solution if you are looking to change a single equation's output.  As mentioned below, `\tag` would help there.

Answer (score 0):

As Svend Mortensen already mentioned:

> Use `\tag{Something}` inside the equation.

Afterwards you might prefer using `\ref{...}` instead of `\eqref{...}` as it produces no brackets.

Minimal working example for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}\tag{Something} A*B
\end{equation}

The equation is \ref{eq:1}. Or \eqref{eq:1}.

\end{document}
```

Will output:

A * B (Something)

The equation is Something. Or (Something).