# Custom cross-reference formats (e.g. "Equation 1" instead of just "1")

Tags: cross-referencing, equations, amsmath

I have an equation system set up as below. When I reference it however, ie. with `\ref{eqn:surfacetension}`, it only prints the number '1', and not 'Equation 1'. How can I modify the code to do that? I apologise if I left out any key bits of code, I only put in the bits that I think are relevant

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\let\mytagform@=\tagform@
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\bfseries(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}\hspace{3mm}}
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\mytagform@{\ref{#1}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\Delta P = \frac{2\gamma}{r} 
\label{eqn:surfacetension}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use the `prettyref` package to customize the format of your cross-references. Add `\usepackage{prettyref} \newrefformat{eqn}{Equation~\ref{#1}}` to your preamble and then use `\prettyref{eqn:surfacetension}` instead of `\ref{eqn:surfacetension}`.

Comment: There are several packages that allow for "advanced" cross-referencing, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36295/cross-reference-packages-which-to-use-which-conflict for an overview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the command `\autoref` (provided by the [hyperref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package) or the command `\cref` (provided by the [cleveref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package) to achieve your objective of having LaTeX provide both the "name" and the "number" of the item being cross-referenced.

[image]

The scope of these commands isn't limited to cross-referencing equations; the commands `\autoref` and `\cref` can be applied to many other items as well. Do peruse the user guides of these packages to learn how to customize, if necessary, the appearance of the cross-references generated by these packages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\setlength{\textwidth}{4in} % just for this MWE
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\Delta P = \frac{2\gamma}{r} 
\label{eqn:surfacetension}
\end{equation}

Here's a cross-reference using \verb+\autoref+: \autoref{eqn:surfacetension}.

And here's a cross-reference using \verb+\cref+: \cref{eqn:surfacetension}.
\end{document}
```

For a more in-depth discussion of the capabilities of various LaTeX cross-referencing methods and packages, I'd suggest you check out [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36312/5001). Shameless self-citation alert!!

Answer (score 1):

At [How do I configure a \ref of a \label to print more than just the number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103546/how-do-i-configure-a-ref-of-a-label-to-print-more-than-just-the-number/103553#103553), I provide a package called `eqcite`.  It sounds similar to what Jubobs mentions above in his comment, except that it allows for the different cases when you want to say "equation 1" (`\eqcite{eq:ref}`) vs. "Equation 1" (`\Eqcite{eq:ref}`) vs. "equations 1 and 2" (`\eqcites{eq:ref1} and \andeqcite{eq:ref2}`).  Maybe `prettyref` does that too.  I'm not familiar with it.