# acronym: First letter capital only short form

Tags: acronyms

Hey I want to wirte an acronym in capital letters without showing the full form. How can I do this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[english,italian,german]{babel}

\usepackage{acronym}

\begin{document}
\begin{acronym}[Bash]
\acro{eq.}{equation}
\end{acronym}
\acs{eq.} should be written with a capital E. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Are you really using this for acronyms?  Or merely for case-sensitive abbreviations (and maybe `\ref`erencing)?  If the latter, maybe something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103546/how-do-i-configure-a-ref-of-a-label-to-print-more-than-just-the-number/103553#103553 could be used...

Comment: I want to use the abbreviation at the beginning of the sentence. How can I get the first letter capitalized? If it's in the middle of the sentence the abbreviation should be in small letters. Is there a way to do it with acronyms?

Comment: My point is, "eq." is not an acronym, but an abbreviation.  So, might you be using the wrong tool altogether?

Comment: I see your point thank you for the suggestion ... but what would you use for abbreviations and link them to a glossary?

Comment: As far as I can see the `acronym` package has no macros to capitalise the first letter of the short form of the acronym. (It does have commands that capitalise the long from: `\Acf` for example.) Presumably because most acronyms are capitalised already (in short form). You can always open a feature request at: https://github.com/oetiker/acronym/issues

Comment: There are also the [`acro`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro) package and [`glossaries`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) maybe those packages have the option you want.