# How to get \ref to write "Theorem 5" or "Lemma 5" Instead of just "5"?

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems

I sometimes change something from "`\begin{theorem}`" to "`\begin{lemma}`" (I have my own commands: `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}` and `\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}`).

But if I just write `\ref{theorem1}`, then I have to manually write "Theorem" before it, which won't change if I turn theorem1 into a lemma.

How do I get this to automatically write "Theorem 1" instead?

Comment: `cleveref`'s `\cref` command could be extremely helpful here.

Comment: See also [Cross-reference packages: which to use, which conflict?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36295/5001) The `\autoref` macro (provided by the [hyperref](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package) and especially the `\cref` and `\crefrange` macros (provided by the [cleveref](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package) can do exactly what you're looking to accomplish.

Comment: @Mico maybe close it as a duplicate of the question you linked, or maybe another one like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5767/how-to-get-more-complete-references ? That would also make the question answered.

Comment: @Marijn - Thanks. I also thought about closing this question as a duplicate. However, the earlier question I referenced in my comment is far more general than what's asked in the question; one would have to read through a lot before getting to the part about the `cleveref` package. Plus, I think that buried within the OP's question is an issue related to how one would cross-reference items that share a common counter; assuming that one wishes to use the `cleveref` package, the solution lies in specifying the `\newtheorem` directives *after* loading `cleveref`.

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't label something `theorem1`, because then it could end up being `Lemma 2`.  You should use a semantic label like `BernoulliConvergence`.  That way, the label will still be correct when you rearrange your document (and you'll have a better chance of remembering the label when you're in a different part of the document).

Answer (score 4):

(posted this answer so that the question can be considered to have received an answer)

You should familiarize yourself with the [cleveref](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref) package and its user commands `\cref` and `\crefrange`. The `\cref` macro (and its start-of-sentence variant, `\Cref`) can take multiple arguments, which will be the arguments of `\label` instructions placed elsewhere in the document. The list of arguments needn't be sorted, and the list can contain labels associated with `equation`, `theorem`, `section`, `figure`, `table`, etc. objects.

Below is a compilable example that creates one instance each of `theorem` and `lemma` envirnonments. Note that `cleveref` is clever enough to distinguish between the two environments even though they share a common counter. It so happens that `cleveref` "knows" the names of these two environments (viz., "Theorem" and "Lemma"); if your document featured numbered environments of a type not already known to `cleveref`, you would need to use `\crefname` instructions to back-fill the missing name information. E.g., if you have an object called `map` (with an associated counter variable also called `map`), then `\crefname{map}{map}{maps}` informs `cleveref` how singular and plural forms of the object should be displayed in a cross-reference.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm} % or: \usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional
\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem} \label{thm:major} \dots \end{theorem}
\begin{lemma}   \label{thm:minor} \dots \end{lemma}
\noindent
Cross-references to \cref{thm:major,thm:minor}.
\end{document}
```