# How exactly does \def\p@figure{Figure~} work?

Tags: macros, floats, cross-referencing, latex-base

I took this line from my thesis style and added it into my document (preceded by `\makeatletter`) and what it does that whenever I used `\ref{figureid}` instead of putting just the figure number, it puts "Figure 1".

I can do the same thing for tables, by having `\def\p@table{Table~)` but what I don't know is what exactly is:

```
\p@figure
\p@table
```

I assume they're used internally by ref, but is there anything more (such as `\p@(object)` is always used as the beginning of something ...)

Comment: Great question! Finally I understand what's happening in [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5767/1235) and the answers to [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2450/1235). (Also nice answers so far.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

These are LaTeX kernel macros that are associated with environments. In simple terms anything that is enclosed with a `\begin{foo}...\end{foo}` is an environment. For example a figure or a table.

Every time you insert a table a counter is incremented. This counter let us call it `foo` has an associated macro named `\p@foo`.  This  macro expands to a printed `reference prefix' of counter
foo.

Any `\ref` to a value created by counter `foo` will produce the expansion of `\p@foo\thefoo` when the `\label` command is executed. `\thefoo` justs prints the value of counter `foo'.

Change `foo` to `figure` or `table` and it will make more sense.

The `\def` part defines the macro. You can for example say `\def\milan{Milan Ramaiyan}` and every time you type `\milan` it will expand too .. Milan Ramaiyan. The `@` symbol is just a special symbol used by TeX and LaTeX to avoid overriding commands accidentally. It needs special treatment and that is why the `makeatletter` and `makeatother` are required.

Answer (score 18):

In addition to Yiannis fine explanation: you may even extend these `\p@` macros such as `\p@figure` to become more than just a prefix. `source2e.pdf` gives hints in section *53.2 An extension of counter referencing*.

This modification

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\refstepcounter[1]{\stepcounter{#1}%
\protected@edef\@currentlabel
{\csname p@#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}}
\makeatother
```

allows you to define `\p@figure` with an argument, which allows more sophistocated formatting. And it's still backwards compatible to the original version. An arbitrary example:

```
\renewcommand*{\p@figure}[1]{\emph{figure~(#1)}}
```

gives *see figure (1)*. This way you may add a prefix and a suffix plus formatting.

Comment: I would strongly advise against redefining one of the base latex commands. It can break packages that redefine it, e.g. hyperref. Rather go down to a deeper level, for example to change the reference to a second level enumerated list from 2a to 2(a)

    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\p@enumii}{\expandafter\p@@enumii}
    \newcommand{\p@@enumii}[1]{\theenumi(#1)}
    \makeatother

Answer (score 4):

A packaged alternative to Stefan's answer is to use the `fncylab` package, which makes the change he mentions and also defines a `\labelformat` macro to manipulate `\p@counter`s easily.  For example, `\labelformat{equation}{(#1)}` makes `\ref` act like `\eqref` when applied to labels on equations.  (I have this activated by default in my documents, actually.  The bare number is rarely useful.)

Answer (score 1):

I used `\usepackage{hyperref}` and applied `\autoref{tab:minimum-cut-set}`. It would generate "Table 1.2" (for instance) what we want to see. However, for algorithm, although "Algorithm" capitalizes but it shows "algorithm 2.1" (for instance).

The caption table, figure are shown properly. Only algorithm occurs the issue as I have mentioned above.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit. `:)`