# How does \@currentlabel work? How does it connect to sectioning commands / headings?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, latex-base

My understanding is that `\@currentlabel` holds a register value. This also applies when `hyperref` is used.

I was having a look at `kpsewhich ltxref.dtx` when I read that `\@currentlabel` handles situations when `\label` is put outside of an environment (this happens when you tack them onto headings e.g. `\section{blah}\label{blah}`).

Its definition is

```
\def\@currentlabel{}
```

This looks to me like effectively initializing a macro. I proceeded to review the document, `source2e`, but I still do not understand `\@currentlabel`.

> To get a proper `\@currentlabel` we have to redefine it for the whole display.  Note that we can't use `\refstepcounter` as this results in `\@currentlabel` getting
>   restored at the wrong and thus always writing the first label to the `.aux` file.

What is meant by **whole display**?

If I create my own sectioning/heading command, is it then a requirement to include `\refstepcounter{CNT}` if I want to be able to tack on `\label{}` to it?

Does `titlesec` automatically add `\refstepcounter{CNT}` to new sectioning commands?

In the sectioning/heading definitions, there is `\refstepcounter{CNT}`. This is the only connection I found to `\@currentlabel`.

> A referencable counter CNT is incremented by the command `\refstepcounter{CNT}`, which sets `\@currentlabel == {CNT}{eval(\p@cnt\theCNT)}`. The command `\label{FOO}` then writes the following on file `\@auxout : \newlabel{FOO}{{eval(\@currentlabel)}{eval(\thepage)}}`

```
\def\refstepcounter#1{\stepcounter{#1}%
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel
       {\csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}%
}
```

It seems like magic how `\subsection{subsec1}\label{subsec1}` results in `\@currentlabel` equal to `1.1`:

```
\newlabel{subsec1}{{1.1}{1}{subsec1}{subsection.1.1}{}}
```

## Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{sec1}
\label{sec1}
\subsection{subsec1}
\label{subsec1}
\subsubsection{subsubsec1}
\label{subsubsec1}
\paragraph{par1}
\label{par1}
\section{sec2}
\end{document}
```

## Relevant `.aux` lines

```
\newlabel{sec1}{{1}{1}{}{section.1}{}}
\newlabel{subsec1}{{1.1}{1}{subsec1}{subsection.1.1}{}}
\newlabel{subsubsec1}{{1.1.1}{1}{subsubsec1}{subsubsection.1.1.1}{}}
\newlabel{par1}{{1.1.1.1}{1}{par1}{paragraph.1.1.1.1}{}}
```

## Related

- [How exactly does \def\p@figure{Figure~} work?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5797/how-exactly-does-def-pfigurefigure-work)

Comment: Please, remove `hyperref` that adds a level of complication that's irrelevant for understanding `\@currentlabel`.

Comment: @egreg Ok, I can adjust my answer. I added it only because it changes the definition of `\newlabel`: from 2 parameters > 5 parameters in the second `{}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The macro is initialized to expand to nothing, but every `\refstepcounter` command redefines it. If you have `\newcounter{foo}`, then part of the job of `\refstepcounter{foo}` is, after having stepped the counter, to do

```
\edef\@currentlabel{\p@foo\thefoo}
```

The job of `\label{baz}` is to issue a command that eventually writes

```
\newlabel{baz}{{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}}
```

but the two macros `\@currentlabel` and `\thepage` will be expanded. The former is expanded immediately, the latter only at shipout time, when the `\write` command to the `.aux` file actually happens.

Note that `\refstepcounter` only does `\edef` and not `\xdef`, so if `\refstepcounter` happens inside a group (an environment, for instance), the value of `\@currentlabel` will not survive the end of the group.

Your quotation about a display refers to some workarounds that need to be made in `eqnarray`; this is not really important, because `eqnarray` should never be used. The `amsmath` package uses different tricks for `\label` inside its alignment environments.

By the way, what's `\p@foo`? For standard counters it is empty, but it can be redefined for a particular counter in order to provide a *p*refix. This is the case for `enumii`, `enumiii` and `enumiv`, for instance, used in `enumerate`.

Just to make an example. Let's see a summary of what happens with

```
\subsection{subsec1}\label{subsec1}
```

The command `\subsection` does, before processing the sectional title, `\refstepcounter{subsection}`. As said before, this redefines `\@currentlabel` using

```
\edef\@currentlabel{\p@subsection\thesubsection}
```

Since the definition is expanded, the current value of `\p@subsection` and `\thesubsection` are stored; the former is empty, the latter, in your code, expands to `\thesection.\arabic{subsection}` and, eventually to `1.1`.

Later `\label{subsec1}` essentially does

```
\protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\newlabel{subsec1}{{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}}}
```

which will (approximately) translate to

```
\write\@auxout{\string\newlabel{subsec1}{{1.1}{\thepage}}}
```

as expansion of `\thepage` is neutralized during `\protected@write`. The `\write` operation is recorded in the main vertical list and will be executed at shipout time; only at this moment `\thepage` will be expanded.

It's immaterial whether you use the alternate method

```
\subsection{subsec1\label{subsec1}}
```

because `\label` will only be processed when the title is typeset. The macro `\label` just gobbles its argument during a `\protected@write`, so this won't show when the argument is moved around. But this is another topic.

Comment: Your example is very helpful. It is still not clear to me is where the counter prefix `\p@subsection` is set. Is it ok to call these counters registers by the way?

Comment: @JonathanKomar The `\p@foo` macro is defined when `\newcounter{foo}` is processed, but it's usually empty. One has to explicitly set it to something different. See lines 352–354 in `article.cls` for an example.