# Patch section command fails

Tags: etoolbox, patching

I'd like to patch the `section` command to add at the end a simple `\label` in a way that is as generic as possible (I don't want to assume the number of arguments of the `section` command for instance, so I can't use `\let` and redefine `\section` directly).

However, the patched version moves the title outside of the section:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\ifdef{\section}{
  \ifpatchable*{\section}{
    \apptocmd{\section}{{\label{DEF}}}{}{}%
  }{}
}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}

\section{Name of my section}

Hello everybody. \cref{DEF}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't append something to section. That will break its handling of arguments. Beside this: automatic labels are mostly useless. They change if you change or move the section command and then the references break.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Really?? What is so special about section? And I'm not sure to understand what you mean when you say that automatic labels are useless: in practice, I'll generate a new label per section, and keep its name in a macro to use later on, more or less as advised here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/600847/116348

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assume that `\section` is the command that sets a numbered section. But that's not the case. Look at the definition of `\section` in [`article.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls?view=co):

```
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
```

`\section`, in fact, calls `\@startsection` with a bunch of other arguments.

If you want to add a generic label to a numbered section, you can use your patch but for `\@sect`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\@sect}{\label{DEF}}{}{}%
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{Name of my section}

Hello everybody. \cref{DEF}

\end{document}
```

Unnumbered section use `\@ssect` internally, so this will only hold for numbered sections. But that makes complete sense. What doesn't make sense in your request if fixing the `\label` independent of the `\section`. It will result in multiply-defined labels if you have more than one section.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also need to patch chapters, subsection, paragraphs... if they exist. What is the equivalent name for them?

Comment: Concerning the label, in practice I change the label programatically in every section using a counter, the `DEF` is only for the example.

Comment: @tobiasBora Follow @Werner's answer and look into the  appropriate `.cls` code.

Comment: @PeterWilson I tried, but I could not even find `\@ssect` in this file ^^ But I guess `\@startsection` defines it internally, and therefore all subsections/paragraphs/... should use the same `\@sect` macro, am I right? What I can't find however is the chapter definition (for instance from `memoir`). I tried to look into this file, but can't even find `\newcommand{\chapter}` https://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memoir.dtx

Comment: @tobiasBora: My patch via `\@sect` covers all sectioning units from `\section` and lower, but not `\chapter`. For reference, `\@startsection` is defined in the LaTeX kernel [`latex.ltx`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co), while the sectioning commands are defined in the respective class files - [`article.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls?view=co), [`book.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co), ...

Comment: ... and [`report.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls?view=co). If you're using a class that defines `\chapter` (like `book` and `report`), then you should be able to `\appcmd{\@chapter}{\label{<label>}}{}{}`.

Comment: Thank's a lot, I'll try!

Comment: Just to let you know, on komascript I can't patch chapters like this, so I created another question here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655029/reliable-way-to-patch-a-chapter-in-scrreport-and-article