# I'm having troubles with the theorem orders

Tags: theorems

My question is really simple, always when I add a new theorem or definition to my thesis I have troubles to redefine the orders of the others theorems/definitions. For example, suppose I have theorem 1.1,1.2 and 1.3. If I add a theorem between 1.1 and 1.2 the theorems 1.2 will become 1.3 and the 1.3 will become 1.4. Because of that I have to redefine every comment I made regarding do theorems 1.2 and 1.3 to 1.3 and 1.4 resp. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Does this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2450/a-better-way-to-reference-theorem-like-environments

Comment: Hi! Have you ever read any LaTeX manual? I would recommend [LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/), section "Cross-referencing" (should be section 5.5).

Comment: Note the `\label` / `\ref` mechanism doesn't just apply to theorems: every numbered construct can be referenced in the same way, sections list items, equations, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve the problem adding a `\label{thm.foo}` to each theorem and then you cite it as `\ref{thm.foo}`.

So it does not matter the order of the theorems, they will be always right cited.

```
\begin{theorem}\label{thm.foo}
bla bla 
\end{theorem}

Theorem~\ref{thm.foo} states that
```

This process is called *crossed reference* and you can label any numbered object (using `\label{}`) and cite it (with `\ref{}`). Note that `amsmath` package provides the command `\eqref{}` for equations, which insert the parentheses automatically.

Comment: Please, add an example.

Comment: @egreg, I was editing. Done!

Comment: @egreg I'm sorry, but instead of the ordered theorem I got a double interrogation sign ??

Comment: @user26832, you need to compile twice in order to update the crossed reference. Also, check if there is some typo on the labels name.

Comment: I couldn't do the same thing with the definitions, I made something wrong?

Comment: @user26832, I guess that you are inserting labels starting with `thm`. But the label name is your choice. I just suggested `thm.foo` to help you to remember that it belongs to a theorem. For example, you can use `def.bla`.

Comment: No, I wrote the names theorem1 and theorem2 to theorems and definition1 to my definition.

Comment: @user26832, the process is the same. Just define the definition, lemma, proposition, etc... as you did for theorems. Give a label to it an cite using `ref{}`. Compile twice.