# Is there a substitute of \ref which writes both the name and the number of the ambient?

Tags: cross-referencing

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,openright,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newenvironment{definition}[1][Definition]{\begin{trivlist}
        \item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{remark}[1][Remark]{\begin{trivlist}
        \item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\begin{trivlist}
        \item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}

\begin{theorem} \label{thm}
4 is a multiple of 2.
\end{theorem}

A consequence of \ref{thm} is that ...
```

As the image shows, the output of `\ref` is "1.0.1". Is there a substitute of `\ref` whose output is "Theorem 1.0.1" instead of only the number "1.0.1"?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. Off-topic. Excuse me if I give you this suggestion: why do not use `amsthm` package?

Comment: Peraphs your question is a duplicate of this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109843/cleveref-and-named-theorems or this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2450/a-better-way-to-reference-theorem-like-environments

Comment: There are several packages that place both the "ambient", as you put it, and the associated number in the cross-referencing call-out. Among them are `prettyref`, `smartref`, `fancyref`, and `theoremref`. (The latter works for theorem-like environments ontly.) There's also `\autoref` of the `hyperref` package. That said, the undisputed current king of cross-referencing packages is `cleveref` and its user macros `\cref` and `\crefrange`. See [Cross-reference packages: which to use, which conflict?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36295/5001) for more information on these packages.

Comment: Incidentally, your code doesn't compile; it makes use an undefined environment named `theorem`. It also lacks `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` directives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,openright,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}

\begin{document}
 
\begin{theorem} \label{thm}
4 is a multiple of 2.
\end{theorem}

A consequence of \cref{thm} or \Cref{thm} is that ...

\begin{remark} \label{rmk}
4 is a multiple of 2.
\end{remark}

A consequence of \Cref{rmk} is that ...

\begin{proof} 
$2*2=4$ 
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]